# Are there any differences between manga and anime copyrights?

Tags: anime-production, manga-production, copyright

According to the law in Japan when a mangaka dies after 50 years the copyrights are annulled and now their manga are public access, in that case what happens with the manga that were adapted to anime? the anime are also public access or only the manga?

If both copyrigths are different then under what circumstances does the anime become public? who should die? the production Company? or who?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. For clarification, could you [edit] and provide some references/sources about that law?

Comment: [著作権法 (Copyright Act of Japan)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Copyright_Act_of_Japan)

Comment: Possibly related: [Who generally owns the rights for a manga or anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/38451/2516)

Comment: Don't have time for full answer, but this article can help: https://openscholarship.wustl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=1598&context=law_globalstudies